# How to simplify a command often used in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

I often use the command

```
cat file.csv | column -s, -t | less –NS
```

whenever I open a CSV file in the terminal, as it nicely formats the output.

Is there a something I can add to my bash profile or somewhere else to type only a few characters to get this whole command? I know about aliases, but I don't know how to use them in this case as the filename for the cat command is always a different csv file.

Comment: A first step: `column -s, -t file.csv | less –NS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function.

```
csvcat() {
  cat "$1" | column -s, -t | less –NS
}
```

Usage:

```
csvcat file.csv
```

Comment: Or `cat "$@"` to list all named files.

Comment: Or `for file ; do cat "$file" ... ; done` to handle all named files in sequence.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether the output from `column` for a file with 5 columns after a file with 3 columns would be messed up.  You'd probably want to run `less` less often than once per file, if only so you can actually achieve an early exit before you've seen the content of all the files.

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple bash script that take filename as command line argument and performs some operation.

Example:

cat pretty_csv

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "$1" | column -s, -t | less –NS
```

This will take the csv file as input.

Further to use it as a command create a softlink.

```
ln -s pretty_csv /bin/pretty_cvs
```

Now I can use it as

```
pretty_csv csvfile
```

Comment: Better to use `"$1"` (and maybe best to use `"$@"`) to handle file names with spaces in them correctly